# No DB host/port required for connect-sqlite3 session store?

Tags: node.js, sqlite, passport.js

Hi i'm looking into sqlite3 for my nodejs/expressjs/passport session management.

In redis, it's like this,

```
app.use(express.session({
  store: new RedisStore({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 6379,
    db: 2,
    pass: 'RedisPASS'
  }),
  secret: '1234567890QWERTY'
}));
```

but in sqlite3 there's no host/port
https://github.com/rawberg/connect-sqlite3

```
var session = require('express-session');
var SQLiteStore = require('connect-sqlite3')(session);

app.configure(function() {
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(express.cookieParser());
  app.use(express.session({
    store: new SQLiteStore,
    secret: 'your secret',
    cookie: { maxAge: 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 } // 1 week
  }));
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});
```

How come ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite like access does not have a server, just a file.
While Redis or mongodb are server based DBs where you connect to a server to connect to the DB.

Answer (score 1):

SQLite needs no host/port because it's [serverless](http://www.sqlite.org/serverless.html).